# SQL Server : pivot or not to pivot

Tags: sql-server, select, pivot

I have a table in which I run a select statement and returns the following data

```
Name    date           skill    seconds  calls
----------------------------------------------
bob     9/2/2016       706      12771    56
bob     9/2/2016       707      4061     16
bob     9/2/2016       708      2577     15
bob     9/2/2016       709      2156     6
```

I want to return like below one row of data:

```
Name date     706sec   706call  707sec  707call  708sec  708call 709sec  709call
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bob  9/2/2016 12771     56       4061     16      2577     15     2156     6
```

My first attempt was a pivot but does not return a single row:

```
Select 
    name, date, seconds, calls, [706], [707],[708],[709],  
from 
    (Select 
         name, date, skill, seconds, calls
     From
         tablecalls 
     Where 
         date between '09/02/2016 00:00' and '09/02/2016 23:59' 
         and name = 'bob') as b
pivot 
    (sum(seconds) for skill in ([706], [707], [708], [709] )) as p1
```

This returns:

```
name    date      calls 706sec  707sec  708sec  709sec
---------------------------------------------------------
bob     9/2/2016    6   NULL    NULL    NULL    2156
bob     9/2/2016   15   NULL    NULL    2577    NULL
bob     9/2/2016   16   NULL    4061    NULL    NULL
bob     9/2/2016   56   12771   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Maybe `PIVOT` is not the right way to do this. Is there another way?

Comment: Well you can use pivot but it will probably end up being less efficient than just using conditional aggregation. For example `select name, date, max(case when skill = 706 then seconds end) [706sec], max(case when skill = 706 then calls end) [706call], max(case when skill = 707 then seconds end) [707sec]... from mytable group by name, date`.

Comment: I tried ZLK suggestion worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

can you format your data in question. I am not sure whether I get youe point?

```
    CREATE TABLE #tt([name] VARCHAR(10),[date] DATE,skill INT,seconds INT, calls int )
    INSERT INTO #tt
    SELECT 'bob','9/2/2016',706,12771,56 UNION all
    SELECT 'bob','9/2/2016',707,4061,16  UNION all
    SELECT 'bob','9/2/2016',708,2577,15  UNION all
    SELECT 'bob','9/2/2016',709,2156,6 

    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT t.name,t.date,c.* FROM #tt AS t
        CROSS APPLY(VALUES(LTRIM(t.skill)+'sec',t.seconds),(LTRIM(t.skill)+'calls',t.seconds)) c(t,v)
    ) AS A
    PIVOT(MAX(v) FOR t IN ([706sec],[706calls],[707sec],[707calls],[708sec],[708calls],[709sec],[709calls])) p
```

```
name       date       706sec      706calls    707sec      707calls    708sec      708calls    709sec      709calls
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
bob        2016-09-02 12771       12771       4061        4061        2577        2577        2156        2156
```

if the count of skill is not fix, you can use dynamic script：

```
    DECLARE @col VARCHAR(max),@sql VARCHAR(max)
    SELECT @col=ISNULL(@col+',[','[')+LTRIM(skill)+'sec],['+LTRIM(skill)+'calls]' FROM #tt GROUP BY skill
    SET @sql='
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT t.name,t.date,c.* FROM #tt AS t
        CROSS APPLY(VALUES(LTRIM(t.skill)+''sec'',t.seconds),(LTRIM(t.skill)+''calls'',t.seconds)) c(t,v)
    ) AS A
    PIVOT(MAX(v) FOR t IN ('+@col+')) p'
    EXEC (@sql)
```